# How to run C# console app in regular console Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, console-application, visual-studio-2019

I switched to the new [Visual Studio 2019 Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/), and when I started my C# console app, I noticed that it's running in the new "Visual Studio Debugging Console", but I'd like to run it in the regular console (like VS 2017, using dotnet command). How can I change it?

I didn't find anything online because this is a brand new feature. Thanks.

Comment: The question isn't clear as there's only one console. The console is provided by the operating system, not Visual Studio. Are you confused by the *title* of the console generated during debugging?

Comment: Ok. What I meant is that the new visual studio is running the apps in their new debugger instead of in dotnet like previous versions, which causes me problems with FreeConsole() imported from kernel32.dll - to hide console while running. The console isn’t hiding but cannot get input into it.

Comment: If you have doubts, check Rich Turner's [Windows Command-Line: Inside the Windows Console](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/07/20/windows-command-line-inside-the-windows-console/) which explains what the Windows Console actually is, how it differs from Linux terminals and the changes being made in Windows 10. You'll see that Visual Studio *can't* change the console even if it wanted to

Comment: @A.naam edit the question and ask what you actually mean, including your code. There's no change in the debuger either though. `FreeConsole()` isn't a common call

Comment: This might be better asked on the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/ide.html?sort=active) site...

Comment: Ok, so what can possibly cause that? In VS2017 it worked perfectly..

Comment: @A.naam what caused *what*? You still haven't asked something specific. FreeConsole is normally *not* used. That's a Win32 API call. On the other hand, direct manipulation of the console pipeline is exactly what's changing now in Windows 10

Comment: To hide the console, after starting the program I’m importing dll (kernel32.dll) and running the method “FreeConsole()” which supposed to hide the console. It worked in VS2017 debugging but doesn’t in the new VS2019 debugging.

Comment: That is the wrong way to do it.  Instead use Project > Properties > Application tab, Output Type = Windows Application.